# Distributing n identical balls in k distinct boxes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can $20$ identical balls be distributed in $4$ distinct boxes, subject to the following conditions:

1. Each box has at least $2$ balls,
2. Each box has an even number of balls?

The distribution of $20$ identical balls in $4$ distinct boxes is equal to the sequence of $20$ $0$'s and $3$ $1$'s. 
So first we put $2$ balls in each box so no box is left empty( We have $1$ way of doing so),
then we distribute the remaining $12$ balls in $4$ boxes(The formula is $C(k + n - 1, k),$ from the theorem: The number of $k$-combinations with unlimited repetition of a set of
$n$ distinct objects is $C(k +n−1, k)$)

Which then implies $C( 12 + 4 - 1, 12)$, so the total number of sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s is $C(15,12) = 15! / (12! * 3!)

I am not sure if the above written is correct and I do not know how to find the answer for the $2^{nd}$ condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to know how many ways there is to place 20 identical balls in 4 boxes.

Given *Each box has an even number of balls*, this becomes equal to the number of ways there is to place 10 pairs of balls in 4 boxes...

Given *Each box has at least 2 balls*, this becomes equal to placing one pair in each box first, then counting **the number of ways there is to place 6 (remaining) pairs of balls in 4 boxes**.

That should cover most of the distance between the problem and the solution.

Comment: So I need to choose to distribute 10 pairs in 4 boxes, that would be C(10, 4) ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919300/r-identical-objects-into-n-distinct-boxes?rq=1